# How to centralize full React PropTypes component definition? Possible storybook bug?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I've looked at existing questions and didn't find one specific to what I'm trying to do, so hopefully someone can help me figure out what I'm missing.

I'm building a `ButtonGroup` component that will display a series of `Button` component items. For good documentation, I'm wanting to provide a good `PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({})` for the `items` prop of `ButtonGroup`.

I'm attempting to use `Button.propTypes` but it doesn't seem to be working (at least in storybook, so maybe this is a storybook/withInfo bug).

I've tried a couple different ways...

```
/** Items that should be buttons */
items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({ ...Button.propTypes }))
```

```
/** Items that should be buttons */
items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape(Button.propTypes))
```

The first doesn't work and just gives me back `[ ... ]` in the withInfo block.

The second actually gives back an index-based keyed object where each key's value is a letter from `Button.propTypes`. :/

[[image: 1]]

Thoughts?

Comment: I imagine this may be related to https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/3493